# Word for "hold softly"?

Tags: single-word-requests

If you search for *[hold](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/hold?s=t)* on Thesaurus, you only find synonyms that mean 'holding strongly'. How about the opposite? What are some words meaning to "hold softly"?

Example:

> Sophia [...] my palm and dropped the jewel onto it.

Comment: This question would be much better with some context or even a concrete example.

Comment: @Affable Geek How about how?

Comment: Caress or even just took would work.

Comment: agrees with AG, "took my hand" would be more natural here.

Comment: In your example sentence, it wouldn't make sense to use "hold" or any related words. You can use "opened" there. Or you can say "Sophia held my hand, opened my palm, and dropped the jewel onto it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Words that come close to holding softly may include:

- embrace
- enfold
- envelop
- cradle
- cushion
- support

In my writing, I find that those are the words that imply a gentleness and softness.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider ***cradle***.

> to hold gently or protectively.
>
> <sub>http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cradle</sub>